# How can I set svg pattern size properly?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I have an SVG that contains pattern and path to fill. I've already figured out how to fill svg with image, but when I do it my svg crops.

There are 4 paths that are generated randomly:
[image: 4 paths]

On my website I try to fill them with image using following code:

**path.js**

```
let paths = []

paths.push(
    "M0,223.2L293,0h450v415.3l-78.5,101.5l-233-50.9L320.4,579l-187.8-27.4L0,223.2z",
    "M743,65.7L342.7,0L44.8,89.2L0,415.5l80.3,126.2l200.8-24.6L484.6,586l150.6-26.8L743,415.5V65.7z",
    "M0,223.2L248.5,0H743v415.3L495.8,552.2l-220.7-56.3L74.3,552.2L0,223.2z",
    "M0,497.2l29.5-142.4L0,122.8L198.2,0l339.6,41.6L726,0v449.4L647.5,532l-238.3-34.8L290.7,567L0,497.2zz"
)

let path = () => {
    return paths[Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(4))];
}

export default path
```

**Home.js fragment**

```
<div className="intro">
    <p>Some text</p>
        <svg width="1540px" height="580">
            <defs>
                <pattern id="pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="580" width="1540">
                    <image height="100%" width="100%" className="introImage" href={introImage}/>
                </pattern>
            </defs>
            <path d={path()} fill="url(#pattern)"/>
        </svg>
</div>
```

**Home.css fragment**

```
.intro {
    margin: 300px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.intro p {
    margin: 0;
    width: 65%;
    font-family: Montserrat medium, sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
}

.intro svg {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

This is what I get:

[image: Result]

As you see, my svg gets cropped and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: you need to set the viewbox

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've tried but it didn't work either. ```viewbox="0 0 580 1540"``` right?